# Using TPL for async call to WCF with TCP binding

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, binding, task-parallel-library, net.tcp

We are using Net Tcp binding to call a WCF service in a self hosted environment. The service worked fine with the client creating a new channel for each request. The client does it by using TPL async await call for each request. The RequestTimeOut is default 10 minutes in the client.

The issue is that after the response is received, we are unable to close the channel explicitly because its an async call.

So the open channel sockets are going on accumulating in the system until it reaches the maxConcurrentSessions. It then waits for the open connections to timeout and the rest of the requests are waiting indefinitely for the channel to close.

This is leading to a huge bottleneck.

My first question is, is this a right approach?

My second questions is, is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: I suggest adding some code, in my opinion it will be easier to understand than an abstract explanation of what's the code doing.

Comment: `The issue is that after the response is received, we are unable to close the channel explicitly because its an async call.` This doesn't make sense to me. I don't understand why you can't close the channel.